# PHP Harmful URL protection

Tags: php

I've made this script, but the 4th line isn't right and I have really no clue how to solve this. I really appriciate if someone helps me. This is my code:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET["url"];
$badsite = array("http://check.com", "http://hotmail.com");

if($url == $badsite) {
echo "This URL is harmful.";
} else {
echo "Not harmful";
header("Location: " . $_GET["url"]);
}
?>
```

So the thing which doesn't work is the following line

```
if($url == $badsite) {
```

How can I make it so it checks if the GET contains a $badsite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to check if the value *equals* the array, you want to check if it's [*in* the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).  Perhaps something like this:

```
if (in_array($url, $badsite)) {
  // ...
}
```

Side note, you don't need (or want, really) this `echo` statement:

```
echo "Not harmful";
header("Location: " . $_GET["url"]);
```

You might get an error by emitting output before sending a header.  But even if you buffer output or in some other way suppress that error, there's no reason to emit output when returning a redirect response.  The browser would display it for only an instant, if at all.  A redirect by itself is a complete HTTP response, no output is required.

Comment: Thanks David! Just what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the function in_array:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
<?php
$url = $_GET["url"];

$badsite = array("http://check.com", "http://hotmail.com");

if(in_array($url, $basite)) {
echo "This URL is harmful.";
} else {
echo "Not harmful";
header("Location: " . $_GET["url"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your buddy David had a faster answer but thanks for letting me know about the article! It's appreciated!